# Get all weeks up to current week / year

Tags: php, date

I have the following code, which gets all 52 past weeks up until the current week.  I want to amend it so that it only includes the current year.  So it should only show the first 4 weeks of January.

```
public static function weeks()
{
    $nextWeek = strtotime('+1 week');

    for($i=0;$i<52;$i++) 
    {
        $date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$i.' week'));
        $nbDay  = date('N', strtotime($date));
        $monday = new \DateTime($date);
        $sunday = new \DateTime($date);
        $monday->modify('-'.($nbDay-1).' days');
        $sunday->modify('+'.(7-$nbDay).' days');

        if($nextWeek > strtotime($sunday->format('Y-m-d'))) {
            $weeks[$monday->format('W')] = $monday->format('j M Y') . ' - ' . $sunday->format('j M Y');
        }
    }

    return $weeks;
}
```

How can I amend the code?

Comment: Instead of counting down, you should start with the 1st of this year and count up.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `date()` with `W` for the week of the year as the upper bound for the loop?

```
public static function weeks()
{
    $nextWeek = strtotime('+1 week');
    /* change the upper bound of the loop using `date('W')` */
    for( $i=0; $i < date('W'); $i++ ) 
    {
        $date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$i.' week'));
        $nbDay  = date('N', strtotime($date));

        $monday = new \DateTime($date);
        $sunday = new \DateTime($date);

        $monday->modify('-'.($nbDay-1).' days');
        $sunday->modify('+'.(7-$nbDay).' days');

        if($nextWeek > strtotime($sunday->format('Y-m-d'))) {
            $weeks[$monday->format('W')] = $monday->format('j M Y') . ' - ' . $sunday->format('j M Y');
        }
    }

    return $weeks;
}
```